# Проверка на лишний код в Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Здравствуйте, есть ли какой-нибудь инструмент на выявления неиспользованного кода в Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кое-что может дать анализ проекта в икскоде (реально это clang analyzer), он способен найти переменные, которые были объявлены, но не использованы (int a = 10; int b = a*2; a++; return b;), да и в целом полезный инструмент.

Также можно попробовать запустить gcov - он способен понять, какую строку сколько раз запускали в рантайме, но он показывает именно то, что было запущено, а это может, в свою очередь, зависеть от входных данных.

Answer (score 2):

Да, очень хорошо с этим справляется AppCode :)
Держу его преимущественно для этих целей.

Comment: Установил, но не нашел, каким инструментов там работать, не уточните?

Comment: Code -> inspect code или в навигаторе слева выбираем папку и на ней правой кнопкой мышки - inspect code.
(но надо дождаться пока индексы по коду построятся, иначе пункт неактивен).

Answer (score 2):

В верхнем меню xCode пункт **Product -> Analyze (Shift + Cmd + B)**.

Comment: Нажал, прошла черта загрузки, и написали Analyze мое приложение Succeeded, и не чего не изменилось, я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: Он покажет все проблемные места, потенциальные утечки, одинаковый код, который нуждается в рефакторинге, проинициализированные и никогда не используемые переменные, непроинициализированные переменные и т.д. в виде синих warnings, там же, где обычно warnings & errors. Если у вас ничего нет, скорее всего все ок. Может быть, он не умеет пнализировать Swift, если используете.